# JDK absent in jdk file

Tags: file, archive, java

I have loaded from Oracle site file:

```
 jdk-6u45-windows-x64.exe
```

It has content:

jre.msi
   jre1041.MST
   jre2052.MST

Where jdk files?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the [`.mst` files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer#Miscellaneous). You run the program, and it triggers [Windows Installer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer), which installs the content from within those files. Once that is complete, the JDK files will be wherever you selected during install (the default is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45` I think [don't have a 64-bit Windows system handy, it's not my main OS and my VMs are 32-bit]; I always go down the "custom" route and install to my preferred location). More in [the Oracle docs for Windows JDK installation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html).

Re your comment:

> So installer using mst files load jdk from internet?

No, the content is actually *in* the `.mst` files themselves. `jdk-6u45-windows-x64.exe` can be used offline.

Comment: understood. So installer using mst files load jdk from internet?

Comment: I asked because I have admin rights only for one directory and cannot run installer, so I suppose extract content manually and use it to run java.

Comment: @user710818: I think the content is actually *in* the `.mst` files. I don't think it does a further download. I don't know that you'll be able to extract the files without running the installer. At least, not without using some special tools from Microsoft. Oracle probably *really* want you to run the installer so they can do the license thing and such.